# Line number and File name PlayFramework

Tags: json, logging, playframework-2.0

How it's possible to get error file name where error occured?

I wrap Action with APIAction to handle errors in Json:

```
  /**
   * Handling Exception and wrapping them into Json.
   * @param f
   * @return
   */
  def APIAction(f: Request[AnyContent] => Result): Action[AnyContent] = {
    Action { request =>
      try { f(request) }
      catch {
        case msg: Throwable => {
          Logger.error("Exception in API", msg)
          InternalServerError(Json.obj("code" -> "500", "message" -> msg.toString, "desc" -> msg.getMessage))
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here what I want to be logged but don't be return to the user
[image]

and here what I get after I wrap everything in JSON 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File name and line number are in `.getStackTrace()(0).getFileName` and `.getStackTrace()(0).getLineNumber` respectively, and should be logged to your log file where they belong.

Showing an exception to the user is not a good idea, and you shouldn't expose the filename and line to the user.

Comment: Agree there's no point of showing filename to the user. I want to log it internally to be able find errors faster.

Comment: Logger.error("Exception in API", msg) will do just that.